# Chrome: Ctrl-K for Google Search, and Ctrl-L for I'm Feeling Lucky

Tags: google-chrome, search, chromium, feeling-lucky

Is there any way to make the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut in Chrome actually do a regular Google search (with the results shown), while still letting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut do an `I'm Feeling Lucky` search?

I can't figure out how to make them use different **default** search engines.

(I'm *not* looking for a way to assign a keyword to a search engine; I need to change the **default** behavior.)

Comment: isn't Ctrl-L shortcut for the omnibox?. ed: Nev mind, I see what your intentions are.

Comment: I doubt it is possible w/o playing with Chrome sources (I wish I am wrong). Chrome is not as modifiable as Firefox. It's the bad side of double-edged sword. The good side is speed and responsiveness not seen in XUL-based UIs. It's worth to point out too, that Chrome devs favor sane hard-coded decisions over thousands of options. This kind of sanity is not always an objective opinion though, thus even Chrome lovers (i.e. heavy users, like me) aren't always happy with its immutable defaults.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change Google Chrome to predict my search AND visit the first result instantly?](https://superuser.com/questions/319992/can-i-change-google-chrome-to-predict-my-search-and-visit-the-first-result-insta)

Comment: @Basj: The question that I answered?

Comment: @Mehrdad this is an automatic message I didn't write myself ; I just indicated that one might be a duplicate of another, and this message has been posted. I just wanted to link them, so if we come here, we can see the other one easily too.

Answer (score 15):

You cannot change the shortcut keys in Google Chrome unless you install an extension. However, you can add a new search engine in Chrome's Omnibox (address bar) by going to

Go to Options > Basic > Default Search > Manage..

[image: Add search engine]

Add in a new search engine and call it `I'm feeling lucky`. Use a suitable shortcut key such as <kbd>l</kbd>. Use the following URL:

http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI=Im+Feeling+Lucky

[image: Type in search engine name, shortcut and URL]

Now go to our address bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, type <kbd>l</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by `your search term` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: I'm Feeling Lucky now available as a search engine]

Chrome will bring you to the first result

[image: Result of I'm Feeling Lucky]

Comment: Still brings up a Google search for me.

Comment: This has stopped working for me. Any idea if there's an update?

Comment: If you disable google instant, even the button on google.com is broken. Here is the link to the google forum that talks about it: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/746JPOTQOWg;context-place=forum/websearch

Comment: This is the URL now: http://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=%s

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an extension, as przemoc said, GC is not a modifiable as FF in that way.

Try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf.  Should work, but some people having an issues with it I believe.