# Can I change Google Chrome to predict my search AND visit the first result instantly?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

[image]

1. Will it be possible to set up Chrome (with a custom search engine, a userscript, or an extension) so that when I type "angelman s" on the Omnibox, it will suggest "angelman syndrome" **and** go right away to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelman_syndrome (the first result for such a search)?
2. Otherwise, will it be possible to set up Chrome so that default omnibar searches are "I'm Feeling Lucky" searches?  That is, typing "fb [enter]" will take me to http://www.facebook.com/ .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 2. I'm Feeling Lucky:

Download and install the [Google SSL search extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lcncmkcnkcdbbanbjakcencbaoegdjlp) and click Add as Search Engine (or whatever it's called).

When the box comes up, *immediately before* the part that says `&q=`, add `&btnI`. Now add the search engine, and it will search I'm Feeling Lucky on Google SSL.

### Bonus:

If you also add `&gnfs`, it wil *only* take to to the website if the results are "good enough". Otherwise, it just shows you search results! :)

In the end, mine looks like this:

> *https://encrypted.google.com/search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&btnI&gnfs&q=%s*

#### Why do I need the SSL search engine?

It's probably the easiest way. You can't modify the built-in Google search engine, so adding a new one is much easier.

Comment: Thanks. Suggest works, Instant works, and hitting enter runs an I'm Feeling Lucky search. There's even spelling correction. The only drawback so far is that if I set up the regular Google search as a custom search engine, I don't get search suggestions on it.  In fact, choosing any suggestion will always fire an I'm Feeling Lucky search -- which is yeah what I wished for.

Comment: @William: Right. You can always bind `g` to a regular Google search, though -- just type `g foo` to search for `foo`. :)

Comment: @William: Also, see [this question I asked a while ago](http://superuser.com/questions/262925/chrome-ctrl-k-for-google-search-and-ctrl-l-for-im-feeling-lucky) -- it's likely what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean, `g foo` will not produce suggestions as I type.

Comment: @William: Really? It does on my Chrome 14.0.835. Not sure what's going on on your computer, then.

Comment: Great solution - Just FYI you don't even have to install the plugin mentioned above, just create a new search engine by copying & pasting the URL above into the Settings -> Manage Search Engines -> Other Search Engine boxes.

Comment: @RyanGriggs: I remember when I last tried it, it didn't work without the extension. Not sure why, maybe it works now though.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has this feature that allows you to derectly search search any site you want, such as wikipedia or youtube. The only thing you have to do is to visit the website once (ie. wikipedia.org) do a search and next time you want to do another search on wiki you just start typing w or wi,press **TAB** and then start typing your actual search.

[image]

The same suggestions will appear but the searchg will be done directly on wikipedia.

Comment: sorry, were you trying to answer #1 or #2? I don't see how your answer relates to my question. Maybe I need to rephrase my question.

Answer (score 2):

Point #1 is possible, provided you've visited it befor. You'll have to enable it from Options.

[image: chrome options]

If you haven't visited before, that's not possible. As for #2 <strike>that's not possible either</strike> have a look at @Merhdad's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/319992/can-i-change-google-chrome-to-predict-my-search-and-visit-the-first-result-instan/320021#320021).

Comment: Actually, #2 *is* possible -- see my answer.

Comment: @Mehrdad Good to know, editing my answer.

Comment: You don’t have to have previously visited a site for Google Instant to work; it’s basically an enhanced version of Google Suggest.

Comment: @Synetechinc. I'm aware of how instant works, I've been using it since they introduced it in `about:flags`. What @william requires: `when I type "angelman s" on the Omnibox, it will suggest "angelman syndrome" and go right away to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelman_syndrome` does require a visit, else it'll just perform a search and not actually go to the site

Comment: You should clarify what exactly it is that does not work without a previous visit. You said it twice, yet I cannot think anything that *requires* a previous visit—certainly not the *Instant Search* nor *Feeling Lucky* functions of this question. (In fact, it’s not clear what exactly your answer is addressing at all. The screenshot you posted has plenty of options and you did not specify which one. I assume it is in regard to the *Instant Search* function, but again, that does not require a previous visit.)