# Google Chrome Shortcut Key for "I'm Feeling Lucky"

Tags: google-chrome, search, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change Google Chrome to predict my search AND visit the first result instantly?](https://superuser.com/questions/319992/can-i-change-google-chrome-to-predict-my-search-and-visit-the-first-result-insta)

I put what I want to find in Google Chrome, type Enter and it give me the results.

Is there a way I can put it and type something like Shift + Enter and goes to "I'm Feeling Lucky"?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/Y1So8rpT-Og/fJ2vuXHj5fkJ) thread.

Comment: [Chrome: Ctrl-K for Google Search, and Ctrl-L for I'm Feeling Lucky](http://superuser.com/q/262925)

Comment: But I wanna keep the regular search with Enter...

Comment: @BernaMariano in case you wish to have the 'enter' you can do it with a little extension...